# Do you like travel deep into the universe?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Is "Do you like travel deep into the universe?" correct in English? Should it be "Do you like travelling deep into the universe?"

Comment: How would anybody know?

Comment: This needs more context.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct in English. However, adding *to* fixes the problem with the least amount of effort: *Do you like to travel deep into the universe?". This is necessary because *travel deep into the universe* is in the direct object slot, and so needs something to make it an object.

The second sentence also works.

The OWL is a good source for how infinitives work: https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/mechanics/gerunds_participles_and_infinitives/infinitives.html

Comment: 'Travel' is also a noun, so why couldn't it be the direct object of 'like'?

Comment: Because "deep into the universe" follows travel, making the whole thing sound unnatural and stilted. That is because that phrase is NOT an idiom and so it needs additional words to make it make sense to the reader.